# Add all elements in array function returning memory values?

Tags: c++

As the title says. My console output is giving me some bogus values during runtime. The main problem is with my sumArray function. It spit out a number that looks kind of like a memory location instead of returning the total value like I need it to. Still relatively new to c++ not sure if I am using functions correctly. Please help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

//constants
const double SCOMMISION_RATE = 0.15;
const double BCOMMISION_RATE = 0.10;
const double LCOMMISION_RATE = 0.20;
const int ArraySize = 3;

//Functions
int arrayType, nums;
long double getHighest(long double array[], int size);
long double getLowest(long double array[], int size);
long double sumArray(long double array[], int size);
long double commisionOfSale(char b, long double c);

//int main
int main()

{
    char categoryOfHomeSold[ArraySize];
    long double choice, totalNumberOfCommisions = 0, TotalSCommisions = 0, TotalBCommisions = 0, TotalLCommisions = 0 , count,
    TotalStandard = 0, TotalLuxury = 0, TotalBasic = 0, realEstateID[ArraySize], sale[ArraySize], commisionEarned[ArraySize], totalAmountCom = 0;

    cout << " Do you have a commisiion to compute? (1= yes, 0= no)";
    cin >> choice;

        for (int count = 0; count < ArraySize; count++)
        {
            cout << "Please enter the Real estate agent ID:  ";
            cin >> realEstateID[count];

            cout << "Please enter model of house sold" << endl << "(B = Basic, S = Standard, L = Luxury) : ";
            cin >> categoryOfHomeSold[count];
            if (categoryOfHomeSold[count] == 'S' || categoryOfHomeSold[count] == 's')
            {
                TotalStandard += 1;
                TotalSCommisions += commisionEarned[count];
            }
            else if (categoryOfHomeSold[count] == 'B' || categoryOfHomeSold[count] == 'b')
            {
                TotalBasic += 1;
                TotalBCommisions += commisionEarned[count];
            }
            else if (categoryOfHomeSold[count] == 'L' || categoryOfHomeSold[count] == 'l')
            {
                TotalLuxury += 1;
                TotalLCommisions += commisionEarned[count];
            }

            cout << "Please enter the selling price of house : ";
            cin >> sale[count];

            cout << "The commission for this sale for Real Estate Sales person ID " << realEstateID[count] << " is: ";
             commisionEarned[count] = commisionOfSale(categoryOfHomeSold[count], sale[count]);
             cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << commisionEarned[count] << endl;
        }
    cout << "Total number of Standard houses commissions computed =" << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << TotalStandard << endl;
    cout << "Total number of Luxury houses commissions computed = " << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << TotalLuxury << endl;
    cout << "Total number of Basic Houses commissions computed = " << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << TotalBasic << endl;
    totalAmountCom = TotalStandard + TotalLuxury + TotalBasic;
    cout << "Total number of all commissions computed = " << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << totalAmountCom << endl;

    cout << "Total amount of Standard House commissions computed = " << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << TotalSCommisions << endl;
    cout << "Total amount of Basic House commissions computed = " << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << TotalBCommisions << endl;
    cout << "Total amount of Luxury House commissions computed = " << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << TotalLCommisions << endl;
    cout << "Total amount of all commissions computed = ";
        totalNumberOfCommisions = sumArray(commisionEarned, ArraySize);
        cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) <<  totalNumberOfCommisions;
        cout << endl;
        system("pause");
}

long double sumArray(long double array[], int size)
{
    int count = 0;
    double total = 0.0;  // Accumulator
    for (int count = 0; count < size; count++)
    {
        total += array[count];
    }
    return total;
}

long double commisionOfSale(char b, long double c)
{

    bool isvalid = true;
    do
        if (b == 'S' || b == 's')
        {
            return  c * SCOMMISION_RATE;
        }
        else if (b == 'B' || b == 'b')
        {
            return  c * BCOMMISION_RATE;
        }
        else if (b == 'L' || b == 'l')
        {
            return c * LCOMMISION_RATE;
        }
        else
        {
            isvalid = false;
        }
    while (isvalid = false);
}


long double getHighest(const long double array[], int size)
{
    double highest = array[0];
    for (int count = 1; count < size; count++)
    {
        if (array[count] > highest)
            highest = array[count];
    }return highest;
}


long double getLowest(const long double array[], int size)
{
    double lowest = array[0]; for (int count = 1; count < size; count++)
    {
        if (array[count] < lowest)lowest = array[count];
    }
    return lowest;
}
```

Comment: Turn your compiler warnings up (`-W3`, `/W3`) then fix the problems it tells you about.  Particularly the ones with `commisionOfSale`.

Comment: If you are not using Visual Studio, and instead are using GCC or a related compiler, add `-Wall` and `-Wextra` to get extra warnings. Warnings mean that the program is syntactically correct (and can compile) but might not be logically correct (and will do goofy things when run).

Comment: *Still relatively new to c++ not sure if I am using functions correctly* -- You should always debug your program yourself first, and then report what you have observed while debugging.  It is frowned upon to simply write a program, sees that it doesn't work, and then not do anything except state that it doesn't work.  [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `while (isvalid = false);` is a bug. But not the only bug. There are several others.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Thank you for the reply. I appreciate all the help. I was able to get this code working after editing commisionOfSale. Still learning how to use the debugger. I guess I assumed since it compiled that there were no errors.